# ActiveMQ Artemis Mqtt connection with HA and Load Balancing - Multiple Broker Addresses

Tags: mqtt, load-balancing, high-availability, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis and I have 3 master and 3 slave brokers

I can connect with sprig boot (jms);

```
spring:
  artemis:
    mode: native
    broker-url: (<maste1>,<maste2>,<maste3>,<slave1>,<slave2>,<slave3>)?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.5&maxRetryInterval=60000&reconnectAttempts=1000
    user:
    password:
...
```

or artemis cli commands(artemis producer and consumer commands);

```
artemis producer --url "(<maste1>,<maste2>,<maste3>,<slave1>,<slave2>,<slave3>)?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.5&maxRetryInterval=60000&reconnectAttempts=1000" ...
```

But I don't know how devices connect with mqtt because i can give only one hostname and port. Also i can only connect one broker with client tools something like
[mqtt.fx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4hPF.png) or [mqttx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL5HN.png).

How should i give all broker urls to client or should i use proxy server (f5, ngnix) to manage urls?

- if i use proxy server, proxy server will manage load balance but artemis also has own load balancer
- if i give all broker addresses to client, i need to update when i add or remove broker

I'm trying to manage ha and load balancing on multiple brokers (acitive/passive)

Comment: What MQTT client are you using?  e.g. MQTT.js can be given an array of broker details that it will try in order if it can't connect to the first (as the `servers` key in the `options` object passed to `connect()`.

Comment: This really depends on what client implementation(s) you use. ActiveMQ Artemis itself has no control over how MQTT clients implement their connection functionality (e.g. support for multiple brokers). If you're interested in a proxy you might be interested in the [connection router](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/connection-routers.html) functionality provided by ActiveMQ Artemis.